# recomendations for spring SEO

Tags: spring, seo, jstl

I have a site made with SPRING mvc and jstl. It has a product catalog on it. Can any one give me some recomendations for making it SEO friendly ? I understand that google's spiders searches in the html pages. However, how do i help them index on what it´s on the database (mysql), like the products and some content ? should i read/do something extra ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open account with google webmasters: http://www.google.com/webmasters
2. Make your URIs SEO friendly [Best way to create SEO friendly URI string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581025/best-way-to-create-seo-friendly-uri-string)
3. Write service that will create sitemap.xml file for your site. Sitemap should include all the pages that are not obvious to the indexing spider bots.

Comment: This has got me on the right direction, thank you!