# Best way to create SEO friendly URI string

Tags: java, string, char, uri, slug

The method should allows only "`0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-`" chars in URI strings.

#### What is the best way to make nice SEO URI string?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Consider [encoding the URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) instead.

Comment: @marcog: It sounds a lot like what SO does to generate SEO-friendly URLs from titles. Mind you, I'd be very tempted to just replace all non-alnum char sequences with a single hyphen; same general effect (if perhaps slightly different in edge cases) but easier to understand.

Comment: @Donal Oh, right. Surely you'd generate a random string from the set of allowed characters though?

Comment: @marcog: What SO does is put that part (which actually *doesn't matter*) on the end of the URL; the path fragment before is an ID which is what actually locates the question. It's safe to use user input for this because the sanitization is defined in terms of a severe whitelist of characters. (Random string? Where did that come from?)

Comment: @Donal Okay, I see what you're referring to. I thought you meant the ID, e.g. 4581025 for this question. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is what the general consensus is:

1. [Lowercase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) the string.

   ```
   string = string.toLowerCase();
   ```
2. [Normalize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#normalize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.text.Normalizer.Form%29) all characters and get rid of all [diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (so that e.g. é, ö, à becomes e, o, a).

   ```
   string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
   ```
3. [Replace all](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) remaining non-alphanumeric characters by `-` and collapse when necessary.

   ```
   string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", "-");
   ```

So, summarized:

```
public static String toPrettyURL(String string) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(string.toLowerCase(), Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", "-");
}
```

Comment: Also recommend removing leading and trailing punctuation.      // remove trailing punctuation
    .replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]+$", "")
    // remove leading punctuation
    .replaceAll("^[^a-z0-9]+", "");

Answer (score 4):

The following regex will do the same thing as your algorithm.  I'm not aware of libraries for doing this type of thing.

```
String s = input
.replaceAll(" ?- ?","-") // remove spaces around hyphens
.replaceAll("[ ']","-") // turn spaces and quotes into hyphens
.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z-]",""); // remove everything not in our allowed char set
```

Answer (score 1):

These are commonly called "slugs" if you want to search for more information.

You may want to check out other answers such as [How can I create a SEO friendly dash-delimited url from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465659/how-can-i-create-a-seo-friendly-dash-delimited-url-from-a-string) and [How to make Django slugify work properly with Unicode strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702337/how-to-make-django-slugify-work-properly-with-unicode-strings)

They cover C# and Python more than javascript but have some language-agnostic discussion about slug conventions and issues you may face when making them (such as uniqueness, unicode normalization problems, etc).